# Overlapping ranges, get unique

Tags: range, unique, overlapping

I have a list of ranges, for example 0-100.
I need to get the unique values that occur only once, as fast as possible.

For example ranges:

```
0 - 10
5 - 20
30 - 40
```

0 - 10 (+11) are unique, none of these numbers came before

5 - 10 are not unique, so don't count them.

11 - 20 (+10) are unique, 30 - 40 (+11) too

This way it returns 32.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the list literally composed of character strings "0 - 10", "5 - 20", etc?

Comment: @GeneBurinsky no, just normal ints

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = range(11)
>>> b = range(5, 21)
>>> c = range(30, 41)
>>> set(i for i in a + b + c)
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40])
>>> len(_)
32
```

Or better:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = xrange(11)
>>> b = xrange(5, 21)
>>> c = xrange(30, 41)
>>> set(chain(a, b, c))
```

And in Python 3:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = range(11)
>>> b = range(5, 21)
>>> c = range(30, 41)
>>> set(chain(a, b, c))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the ranges are sorted in ascending order by the lower bound of the range. I will assume for this solution that this will always be the case.

Basically, the idea would be to iterate through the ranges, adding unique values to a count variable each time.

To determine where the unique values start, compare where the previous range ended to where the new range starts.

If the new range's lower bound is less than the old upper bound, I.e. 0-10 then 5-20, per your example, the unique values will start at the previous upper bound + 1 (I.e. upper bound is 10, unique starts at 11). If the new upper bound is less than the old upper bound, there are no new values to add(I.e. 0-10, then 2-7).

Finally, if the new lower bound is greater than the old upper bound (I.e. 5-20 then 30-40), then all the new values are unique.

Pseudo code:

```
var count = 0, lowerBound = 0, upperBound = 0;
foreach range in ranges:
   if range.lowerBound <= upperBound:
      if range.upperBound < upperBound:
         continue;
      else:
         lowerBound = upperBound + 1;
   else:
      lowerBound = range.lowerBound;
   upperBound = range.upperBound;
   count += upperBound - lowerBound + 1;
```